# Difficulty Ignoring Route In Asp.Net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

The following exception is being thrown after an IgnoreRoute method call:

> The controller for path
>   '/anything.php' was not found or does
>   not implement IController.

However, I have the following method in my MvcApplication class:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.RouteExistingFiles = false;

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.IgnoreRoute("{*php}", new { php = @"(/?.*/)*\.php$" });

    // Some calls to routes.MapRoute occur here.
}
```

I'm not really sure why the exception is being thrown if the Mvc website is set up to ignore such routes.  Also, I'm testing the site by hitting F5 in Visual Studio and then replacing http://localhost:12345/ by http://localhost:12345/anything.php.  Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your regular expression to make sure it's .NET compatible?

Try replacing your regex with this regex:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allphp}", new {allphp=@".*\.php(/.*)?"})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, George!  I'm now getting the error "File does not exist."...  Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: @Andrew it happens if that file doesn't exist wherever you requested it.  So if you don't have a anything.php in the root of your web folder, you'll get the 404 for that.  Also recognize that you need to make sure IIS and ASP.NET handle php correctly (which will vary on your needs, and I'm not qualified to talk about running PHP side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC).

Comment: Thanks again.  I'll try to get the request stopped via IIS, if possible.  The website is completely asp.net mvc, but it keeps getting these automated requests for php pages, probably by devious automated processes running on other servers.  I just wanted to ignore the errors.  Thanks!

Comment: I have a same scenario, but need to ignore <script></script>  tags from the route, till have not not got any answers related

Comment: @SandeepPandey There shouldn't be any script tags in the route. You'd need to post a new question with your particulars.